# without turn on location not showing current location in android

Tags: android, google-maps, currentlocation

Hi in the below code am setting current location to my application.If it is turn on the location by manually it was showing current location.

If am not turn it on it was showing nothing in my map.

But i want to display the permission to turn on location and have written the code but it is not working .

can any one please help to resolve this issue.

MapsActivity.java:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
        private static final int LOCATION_REQUESTOR = 101;
        @Bind(R.id.back)
        TextView mBack;
        @Bind(R.id.location)
        TextView mLocation;
        @Bind(R.id.toolBar)
        Toolbar mToolBar;
        @Bind(R.id.map_address)
        TextView mMapAddress;
        @Bind(R.id.latitude)
        EditText mLatitude;
        @Bind(R.id.longitude)
        EditText mLongitude;
        @Bind(R.id.setLocation)
        Button mSetLocation;
        private Location mLastLocation;
        private GoogleMap mMap;
        Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
        private SharedPreferences mPref;
        private SolarBLEPacket mSolarController = new SolarBLEPacket();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            ButterKnife.bind(this);
            mPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        }

        protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            mLastLocation = location;
            if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
            }

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            //move map camera
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));

            mLongitude.setText(latLng.longitude + "");
            mLatitude.setText(latLng.latitude + "");

        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            mMap=googleMap;
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

            //Initialize Google Play Services
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //Location Permission already granted
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    //Request Location Permission
                    checkLocationPermission();
                }
            }
            else {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
        public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle(R.string.title_location_permission)
                            .setMessage(R.string.text_location_permission)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                                }
                            })
                            .create()
                            .show();


                } else {
                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                        // location-related task you need to do.
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            //Request location updates:
                            //.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
                        }

                    } else {

                        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                        // functionality that depends on this permission.

                    }
                    return;
                }

            }
        }
        @OnClick(R.id.setLocation)
        public void onClick() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            String longtitude = mLongitude.getText().toString();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(longtitude)) {
                intent.putExtra(Constants.LONGITUDE, longtitude);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.please_enter_longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String latitude = mLatitude.getText().toString();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(latitude)) {
                intent.putExtra(Constants.LATITUDE, latitude);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.please_enter_latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String latCommand = mSolarController.generatePacket("lat " +latitude,"00");
            String longitudeCmd = mSolarController.generatePacket("lon "+longtitude,"00");
            mPref.edit().putString(Constants.LAT_COMMAND,latCommand).commit();
            mPref.edit().putString(Constants.LONG_COMMAND,longitudeCmd).commit();
            mPref.edit().putString(Constants.LAST_LATITUDE,latitude).commit();
            mPref.edit().putString(Constants.LAST_LONGITUDE,latitude).commit();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
        @OnClick({R.id.back, R.id.location})
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.back:
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent());
                    finish();
                    break;
                case R.id.location:
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    String longtitude = mLongitude.getText().toString();
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(longtitude)) {
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.LONGITUDE, longtitude);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.please_enter_longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    String latitude = mLatitude.getText().toString();
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(latitude)) {
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.LATITUDE, latitude);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.please_enter_latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    Float lat = Float.parseFloat(latitude);
                    if (lat > 90 || lat < -90) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.longitude_alert, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    float lan = Float.parseFloat(longtitude);
                    if (lan > 180 || lan < -180) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.latitude_alert, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    String latCommand = mSolarController.generatePacket("lat "+latitude,"00");
                    String longitudeCmd = mSolarController.generatePacket("long "+longtitude,"00");
                    mPref.edit().putString(Constants.LAT_COMMAND,latCommand).commit();
                    mPref.edit().putString(Constants.LONG_COMMAND,longitudeCmd).commit();
                    mPref.edit().putString(Constants.LAST_LATITUDE,latitude).commit();
                    mPref.edit().putString(Constants.LAST_LONGITUDE,latitude).commit();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just checking the permission, You need to check whether is location is enable of the device or not.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean gps_enabled = false;
boolean network_enabled = false;

try {
    gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
} catch(Exception ex) {}

try {
    network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
} catch(Exception ex) {}

if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
    // notify user
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled));
    dialog.setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.open_location_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
                //get gps
            }
        });
    dialog.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    dialog.show();      
}
```

Comment: whats happening ?